# Migration from a BPEL Engine to a BPMN Engine

Tags: bpel, business-process-management, bpmn, business-process

I'm looking for a some kind of generic guide about the steps to perform during the migration from a BPEL engine to a BPMN engine. Maybe there is some kind of documentation regarding this topic from someone who already did it. Maybe somebody could sketch the necessary steps here. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything appropriate about this topic on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task.

Do you need to generate "code" (From Bpel to Bpmn) or a transparent migration?

Please take a look on these articles, they show some differences between Bpel and BPMN.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/%20bpelbpm

https://redstack.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/what-bpm-adds-to-soa-suite/

Comment: Hi Wanderley, thank you for your links. The focus is on a transparent migration, but it would be also interesting if there are some tools for automatic/semi-automatic generation of BPMN structures from BPEL. I couldn't find any appropriate information about such tools... Maybe you know more about this topic? Regards